# how do I do a count distinct group by in ms access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
SELECT [dataset].[ID], count(distinct([dataset].dates)) AS distinct_dates
FROM [dataset]
GROUP BY [dataset].[ID];
```

this gives the error `UnDefined function Distinct in expression`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two levels of aggregation:

```
SELECT [dataset].[ID], COUNT(*) AS distinct_dates
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT id, dates
      FROM [dataset]
     ) as d
GROUP BY [dataset].[ID];
```

Strictly speaking this is not 100% the same, because this would count `NULL` as a separate value (but `count(distinct)` ignores `NULL` values).  So, to be identical, you would need to use:

```
SELECT [dataset].[ID], COUNT(dates) AS distinct_dates
```